# Fourier series of $(-1)^{[x]}$

Tags: real-analysis

I've been trying to find the Fourier series of $f(x)=(-1)^{[x]}$ ($[x]$ is the floor function) on $[-2,2]$.

I've drawn the graph and noticed that $f$ is odd and therefore $a_n = 0, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$. Calculating the coefficient $b_n$ resulted in $b_n = \frac{2}{n\pi}\left(-2\cos(\frac{n\pi}{2}) + 1 + (-1)^n\right)$. However when plotting the series, I does not look like $f(x)=(-1)^{[x]}  $. How can I best approach finding Fourier series for this type of functions?

Comment: $f$ is odd $2$-periodic so $a_n=0$,
$b_n = \frac{1}{2} \int_{-1}^1 f(x) \sin(2 \pi n x/2)dx= \int_0^1 \sin(2 \pi n x/2)dx = ?$

Comment: Why do you have $\sin(2\pi nx/2)$? I don't see where the first $2$ comes from.

Comment: $b_n =  \int_{-1}^1 f(x) \sin(2 \pi n x/2)dx= \int_0^1 \sin(2 \pi n x/2)dx = ?$ then $f(x) = \sum_{n \ge 1} b_n \sin(2\pi n x/2)$

Comment: But why do you use $2\pi n x/2$ for the argument of $\sin$, instead of $\pi n x/2$. (Formula: $b_ n = \frac1L \int_{-L}^L f(x) \sin (n \pi x/L) $).

Comment: Has it something to do with the period of $f$?